# Facebook and dotnetopenauth issue

Tags: facebook, openid, dotnetopenauth

We established an OpenID provider at BioSignID.com base on DotNetOpenAuth. 
(the authentication is base on signaturs with silverlight client...)
As we tried to login to facebook we encounter a problem with IE (6,7,8). 
In FF and Chrome the loggin process was fine.

On the server logs I can see the FB reqeust but the user somehow is NOT authenticated. 
In fiddler I can see that the authentication cookie not sent.

I've tried to transfer the server.aspx calls to https but then I cannot make the connection between my FB account and my BioSignId account.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you please describe more what you're doing?  Are you trying to log into Facebook using your BioSignID.com Provider?  Are you writing a javascript client that's trying to access Facebook?  It's difficult to know what you're trying to achieve from your question.

Comment: Hi 
The problem occur when I tried to log into facebook with my BioSignID.com identity. Somehow only IE browsers don't send the asp.net auth cookie so the user not authenticated on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Resolve that. 
Even IE browsers send the session cookie so base on it I can check and Identify the user. 
Thanks